# How to calculate Running Total in MySQL recursive CTE?

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a reservation database contents start, end dates as well as the no of Adult and Child.
I am creating a query that computing everyday total number of booked room with total adult and child.
Each record represents one room therefore counting ID gives me total number of rooms. However, in recursive part my running total not brings the correct sum of Adult and Child.

Following is my table and query structure. Appreciate if you would assist to coorect.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `res_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `res_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `adult` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `child` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

Query:

```
SET @runadt:=0;
SET @rundhd:=0;
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      (@runadt := @runadt + adult) AS adult_fc,
      (@runchd := @runchd + child) AS child_fc,
      res_start as date_from,
      res_end as date_to,
      res_end as _du
    FROM bookings
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      id,
      adult_fc,
      Child_fc,
      DATE_ADD(cte.date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY),
      DATE_ADD(cte.date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY),
      _du
    FROM cte 
    WHERE DATE_ADD(date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY) < _du
)
SELECT COUNT(id), adult_fc, child_fc, date_from FROM cte
GROUP BY date_from
ORDER BY date_from
```

[Current Query Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGiUa.png)

Comment: I am not seeing where recursion comes into it. Please add sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Do NOT use variables. Simply add expressions with window functions into outer query.

Comment: @P.Salmon *I am not seeing where recursion comes into it.* OP generates dates list based on starting and finishing date.

Comment: Provide some sample data as complete CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and show desired output for this data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly then

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, res_start, res_end, adult, child, res_start res_date
         FROM bookings
       UNION ALL
         SELECT id, res_start, res_end, adult, child, res_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte
         WHERE res_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY < res_end )
SELECT *, 
       SUM(adult) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY res_date) cumulative_adult, 
       SUM(child) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY res_date) cumulative_child
FROM cte
ORDER BY res_date, id;
```

Or maybe you need in simple

```sql
SELECT *, 
       adult * (1 + DATEDIFF(res_end, res_start)) cumulative_adult,
       child * (1 + DATEDIFF(res_end, res_start)) cumulative_child
FROM bookings;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3921548ae9dcb1793cae3a0de55f7aba)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not the result I want to achieve,
for example:

```
1st booking 1 room 2 adult 1 Child, 2021-01-10  /  2021-01-12

2nd booking 1 room 3 adult 1 Child 2021-01-11 / 2021-01-13
```

Result will be as follow:

```
Date               Room          Adult        Child
2021-01-10     1                 2               1
2021-01-11     2                 5               2
2021-01-12     1                 3               1
```

Comment: My query above brings date and Room correctly but I couldnt get the adult & child

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      adult,
      child,
      res_start as date_from,
      res_end as _du
    FROM bookings
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      id,
      adult,
      Child,
      DATE_ADD(cte.date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY),
      _du
    FROM cte 
    WHERE DATE_ADD(date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY) < _du
)
SELECT 
      date_from,
      COUNT(id) AS room,
      SUM(adult)  cum_adult, 
      SUM(child)  cum_child
FROM cte
GROUP BY date_from
ORDER BY date_from
```